# translating a few words on this microprocessor block diagram

Tags: translation

I am trying to understand an embedded system tutorial in Chinese

I can use Google for the text part but have problems with comments in Chinese on a figure

Please help me understand the meaning of the phrases in this block diagram

[image]

Comment: Here're some key words: 初始化-initialization; 工具-tool; 程序-program; 区域-area; 数据-data; 存储-store; 配置-setup; 事件-event; 按键-key; 铃声-ring; 提示音-warning tone; 其他-other.

Comment: @songyuanyao so 9 is ring setup? I that ring as in telephone ring?

Comment: I can't tell it's telephone ring or not with current context; I suppose it's some kind of configuration about sound.

Comment: @user17915 Yes, the word is used to describe a doorbell/telephone ring.

Comment: 存储 could be *storage*. 配置could be *configuration*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Initialisation and tools for Sink
2. CSR8670 application
3. application context
4. data storage area
5. initialize configuration
6. event configuration
7. key press configuration
8. LED configuration
9. ringtone configuration
10. notification alert/sound configuration
11. other configurations
12. Connection
    lib initialization
13. HFP, A2DP, AVRCP initialisation